# Loop without IF or SWITCH condition within it

Tags: c#

I want to print the number like as shown below using the `loop` and without using `if` or `switch` condition.

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
5
6
6
7
8
9
9
10
```

**Note**: When loop comes to number 5 it has to iterate 3 times and when it comes to 6 and 9 it has to iterate 2 times.

**Example**:

I have the following code which prints numbers same as they meet the condition.

## My Try:

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print Numbers 1 To 10");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
            
               Console.WriteLine( i==5 || i == 6 || i == 9 ? i.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + i.ToString() : i.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a fixed set of numbers is that true?
If so, why not just throw them into an array and iterate over it?

Comment: The only way to do that is to determine a mathematical relationship between a number and the times it needs to iterate.  If there is no mathematical relationship, then you have to have conditional logic like you have in your code.

Comment: Shall 5 be printed out *two* times (as in the example) or *three* times (as the code does)

Comment: What is the purpose of this question.  Is this homework?  Maybe http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, Can you please explain how to do this mathematical relationship?

Comment: matehmatical means like for example 5 has only 1 3's in it and 6  has 2 3's int it and 9 has 3 3's in it some sort of relationship is requires

Comment: If this is a homework assignment then you should post the actual assignment instructions for this specific problem.  That can help us avoid any surprise rules in your assignment.  Don't worry about tipping us off to the fact that you're asking about homework, everyone is assuming that this is homework anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(i - i / 6 - i / 7 - i / 9 + i / 12 - i / 13 + i / 14);
```

At position `i = 6`, `i = 7`, `i = 9` and `i = 13` you want to repeat the previous value, so subtract `i / _`, but need to add `i / 12` and `i / 14` because from `12` and `14` subtractions `i / 6` and `i / 7` start counting twice.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the `?` mark operator is an if statement. So using that is out. But you could make an array:

```
int[] myNums = {1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,8,9,9};
for (int i = 0; i < myNums.length; i++) {
 Console.WriteLine(myNums[i]);
}
```

Comment: populating the array would require conditional blocks. if he's going to do that, he might as well use his original code.

Comment: I'm not sure it's entirely correct to say `?` is an if statement, while they may have similar functionality, they have quite different semantics.  It could be that if this is homework and specifically if statements are ruled out, it may be to make you think about using alternatives, such as the ternary.

Comment: I down-voted this answer because there's simply too high a chance that it's not useful to the OP, let alone future visitors of this question.  It seems to violate the spirit of "using loops", and even though the answer is not entirely clear on whether or not that's allowed, an unclear answer is no excuce for a potentially wrong answer.

Comment: The question seems to suggest that the OP needs an algorithm to determine how many times a number should be printed based on some set of (unknown to us) rules, not to specify explicitly what should be printed, which is what this does.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the relationship between the number and the iteration count in a dictionary. The number to print would be the key and the number of times to print would be the value. You could then achieve what you need with then following:

```
var printNumbers = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 },{ 3, 1 },{ 4, 1 },{ 5, 3 }, { 6, 2 }, { 7, 1 }, { 8, 1 }, { 9, 2 } };

        foreach (var num in printNumbers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < num.Value; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num.Key);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I down-voted this answer because there's simply too high a chance that it's not useful to the OP, let alone future visitors of this question.  It seems to violate the spirit of "using loops", and even though the answer is not entirely clear on whether or not that's allowed, an unclear answer is no excuce for a potentially wrong answer.

Comment: The question seems to suggest that the OP needs an algorithm to determine how many times a number should be printed based on some set of (unknown to us) rules, not to specify explicitly what should be printed, which is what this does.